# Now I've boxed my ABC's

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, letters

Well, almost.  Can you figure out my letter-classifying system, and where to put W, X, Y, and Z?

[image: Letters A-U in boxes]

Comment: Just FYI!  There is is definitely no apostrophe for plurals in English!  ABCs is just ABCs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The letters should be boxed like this:

> [image]

because they are boxed according to

> the pitch they are sung at in the [Alphabet song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_song)!

The title of the puzzle

> is a reference to the last line of the song: "Now I know my ABCs. Next time, won't you sing with me?"